# Submit form from a link outside the form with a variable that the link sends to the form?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, hyperlink

I want to submit a hidden form using javascript that is activated from an external link that sends a variable to an input depending on what link is clicked.

Link

```
<a title="Go to Store" class="link_pointer" onclick="submit_form('my_emai@gmail.com');">Click Here</a>
```

Form

```
<form id="submit_form" action="{% url "login" %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="email"/>
</form>
```

How can this be achieved using JavaScript where the links have different emails and when you click the link the form is submitted with the input value of the email in the link?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the parameters through a url to a view and responding with a json response that submits the form with the respective parameters.